# JavaFX stuff won't reference

Tags: java, javafx

I don't think I can explain it well, but here it goes.

It seems that anything referencing something JAVAFX specific, fails... I think.

It's not the code because its common examples from the internet on how to make a sample javafx  program.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `jfxrt.jar` to your path, or enable JavaFX support for your chosen platform in Netbeans.

(In Netbeans), right click on your project, go to properties, click libraries, then manage platforms, then if you have a JavaFX tab there, click on it and select "enable JavaFX".

If you don't have that tab, then exit out of the platform manager, click "Add Jar/Folder", and then navigate to jfxrt.jar (usually in jre/lib in your jdk installation directory) to add it that way.

Comment: I took the "If you don't have that tab, then exit out of the platform manager, click "Add Jar/Folder", and then navigate to jfxrt.jar (usually in jre/lib in your jdk installation directory) to add it that way." option, and I'm getting a slightly different error now---   but still indicates netbeans doesnt know about javafx. this  error repeats for every reference.                           error: cannot find symbol
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
  symbol:   class PhongMaterial
  location: package javafx.scene.paint

Comment: Are you sure you're using Java 8, not Java 7? The Java 8 jfxrt.jar will be found in `jre/lib/ext` instead. Using the old one will obviously cause problems.